# Maintaining index of multiple react-slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I am making a react project. I have a page where have to use multiple react-slick elements. I want to maintain index of each slick element. Currently I am doing this

```
render() {
            var settings = {
            arrows: true,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            afterChange: function(currentSlide){
            this.setState({
            currentSlide: currentSlide
        })
            console.log(currentSlide);
        }.bind(this)
        };
            return (

            <div className="main-wrapper">

            {/*carousel responsive1*/}

            {this.state.users.map((item,i)=>{
                return  <div className="main-wrapper-mobile">
                    <div className="carousel responsive1">
                        <div className="mask">
                            {/*slideset */}
                            <div className="slideset">
                                {/*slide*/}

                                <Slider {...settings}>
                                    {item.activities.map((item1,i)=>{
                                        return <div className="slide">
                                            <div className="content__item d-flex">

                                                <div className="content__photo">
                                                    <img className="content__img" src={item.image_url}/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="article">
                                                    <p className="article__text">{item.comment_text}</p>
                                                    <ul className="article__controls">
                                                        <li className="article__control-item"><a href="#">visual <i
                                                            className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                                        <li className="article__control-item"><a href="#">text <i
                                                            className="fas fa-comment-dots"></i></a></li>
                                                        <li className="article__control-item"><a href="#">edited <i
                                                            className="fas fa-edit"></i></a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <div className="article__icon">
                                                        <a href="#" className="article__icon--blue"> <i
                                                            className="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="#" className="article__icon--gray"><i
                                                            className="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    })}

                                </Slider>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Brief explaination of above code:

I have an array of users. Each user is assigned a slider. That is why I am mapping the users array and rendering  in each mapping.

Currently the "currentSlide" parameter in "settings" sets the state "currentSlide" to whatever currentSlide is. The problem is the same state changes for all the sliders. There is no way to keep track of which slider is getting slide. I should be able to change or maintain slider and it's corresponding index. How should I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/629 you can find it here

Comment: This is not what I want. The solution of the link you have give is already in place in the code in my question. I asked question for multiple sliders. Maintaining index for one slider is straight forward. In case of multiple sliders, maintaining index of each slider is what I am looking for.

Comment: Question is still ambiguous because in single slide it is quite easy to get current index as you sad but when if there is more than one `slidesToShow` which index do you would like to get... Suppose there are three `slidesToShow = 3` then we get index of all three then what is the problem here?

Comment: How to get which slideshow the user is sliding. Suppose there are 3 slideshows. User goes to first one and slides two times. Now user goes to second one and slides 3 times. Now how to record and maintain these two events seperately?

Comment: This question concerns if the component provides ability to be a controlled component.
Unfortunately my efforts looking at the api render that the answer is negative...

Answer (score 2):

You would have to dynamically create a new settings object per instance of react-slick, and attach an extra value (in this case I just added an extra string called "Slider1" or "Slider2", etc.) inside the callback function of afterChange. Basically whenever the user changes the slides of on a particular react slider, the `state` under `currentSlide` would have an object that looks like this `{indexSlider: "Slider1", indexOfCurrentSlide: 2 }`. Let me know if this clarifies what you are asking for. I figured this is one way of distinguishing which Slider has been changed.

```
const MultipleSliders = () => {
  const [ currentSlide, setCurrentSlide ] = useState({})
  const generateSettings = (indexSlider) => {
    return {
      arrows: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      afterChange: (indexOfCurrentSlide) => {
        setCurrentSlide({
          indexSlider,
          indexOfCurrentSlide
        })
      }
    }
  }
  const settings1 = generateSettings('Slider1');
  const settings2 = generateSettings('Slider2');
  const settings3 = generateSettings('Slider3');
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Slider {...settings1}>
        {/* content goes here */}
      </Slider>
      <Slider {...settings2}>
        {/* content goes here */}
      </Slider>
      <Slider {...settings3}>
        {/* content goes here */}
      </Slider>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer for this site and is likely to get you voted down. If you take all (or just the relevant part) of the posted code and post it as a fixed version, that is the de facto standard for answering questions here. Give it an edit or delete before you lose some reputation. :)